# Navigate to webpages and click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, download

Using a simple javascript snippet on google chrome, I am attempting to navigate to various webpages and downloading select files from them.

Here is my code so far..

```
var thumbnails= document.getElementsByClassName('mythumbnails')
var arr=Array.prototype.slice.call(thumbnails)

timeToCloseWindow=10000;
  function work() {
  if(thumbnails.length==0) return;
  var url = arr.shift();
  var openWindow = window.open(url.href);
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("download-icon")[0].click()
    openWindow.close();
    work();
  }, timeToCloseWindow);
}

work()
```

Unfortunately, I run into the error `Cannot read property 'click' of undefined`. I have also tried using a for loop with a sleep condition with the same error. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
window.location = url.href;
document.getElementsByClassName("download-icon")[0].click()
```

Comment: Please share your markup. Where is the element with class `download-icon`?

Comment: The element looks like the following `<a class="download-icon" data-tb-test-id="action-download-detail" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="0" title="Download"></a>`. If I have navigated to the page manually, the command `document.getElementsByClassName("download-icon")[0].click()` works

Comment: Well, it looks like `document.getElementsByClassName("download-icon")` returns an empty node list. Did you verify that it contains an element?

Comment: Yeah I have navigated to the website and I manually run the click command it runs. However if I use the script to navigate to the page, it returns the empty node.